# Error: not.exe has stopped working - When trying to build LLVM

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, llvm

I am trying to build LLVM on windows, and everytime I do so I get to a certain point and then recieve an error that says `"not.exe has stopped working"` It pops up on the desktop about 15 times.

I am not sure what is going on, but when I check the error in Visual Studio I receive this:

```
Error   4   error : Couldn't execute program 'C:/Users/Cyborg/Documents/Developer'The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.   C:\Users\Joe\Documents\Dev\llvm\test\CUSTOMBUILD    check-llvm
```

I receive this error 5-7 times depending on how fast I click the error that pops up on the desktop. So clearly this issue is happening because of that.

The fault module is: `MSVCR100.dll`

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you're getting the error since I don't build or use LLVM on Windows. Since no one else has chimed in, I'll try to give a hint or two.

"not.exe" (or "not" under Linux) is a little LLVM helper program used when running the lit based regressions tests. It is used to execute a program and return a good exit status if the program fails and a bad exit status if the program doesn't fail.

I'm guessing that "CUSTOMBUILD check-llvm" (what ever that is) is attempting to run the regression tests and your getting your mysterious error as a result whenevr "not" is used.

I hope that helps.